# How would you go about making a polarizing camera filter in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shaders

I know that since Cycles is not a spectral raytracer, it cannot simulate dispersion and other wave properties like polarization. How could you fake a controllable polarizing filter that can be implemented *outside* of a water/glass shader? For reference, this is the effect I would be looking to achieve, without have to tweak the shader of the water/glass objects.

https://i.imgur.com/8ycFH0K.gifv

Comment: It's impossible without animating/tweaking the water/glass materials.

Answer (score 1):

[image: final]

You can fake this effect from the material point of view not from Camera or global as @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny stated in the comments.

This effect can be used to control object **Roughness** (best with **Principled BSDF**) or for mixing material/shader with **Transparent Shader** (water, glass) or just for mixing different materials.

### Scene setup

[image: s_setup]

Most important thing here is to have object in front of **Camera** which will be our "filter".

I've used **Plane** parented to **Camera** for ease of use.

### Materials

**"Filter"**

It's only **Transparent shader**. Pure white value for invisible filter or a little bit darker to make it more realistic as polarization filters tend to be darker.

**Water/Glass/Mix**

[image: wgm]

In this setup we are using **Light Path > Transparent Depth** as a mix factor to utilize our transparent filter. **Math** node controls how strong this mix is. You can make material fully transparent or leave some reflections as I did.

To make this process faster along other materials in the scene you can create simple group out of **Light Path**, **Math**, **Transparent** and **Mix** exposing **Math** socket and shader socket.

[image: group]

[image: group_2]

**Other materials**

You can use **Light Path > Transparent Depth** (with **Math**) as a **Roughness** input but this method seems to be way to artificial. If I come with better idea than this I'll make an edit.

Comment: You should probably use a Refraction shader instead of Transparent to keep it realistic - so you still have the refraction of the surface, just no reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd animate the color of the Glossy BSDF shader for the water or glass material.  I'd setup a scalar value source with keyframed values from 1 to 0, feed it to a color ramp (in case I want to tweak the exact color) and that would feed the Glossy color input.   At least one light source in the scene needs to be positioned to make glare when that scalar value is at 1.

Alternatively, you could position one (or more) lights right where they make glare in the rendered final image, and animate their values down to zero. But that would also affect lighting on the surrounding objects.  Some hocus-pocus with light path types might let you shine a specific light source onto only certain objects such as the water, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's practical.

That's for shiny objects.  For the polarized light shining on dull materials such as those books, I'd have to think some more.